# Ionic pass value from app.component.ts to remote-service.ts using http service

Tags: wordpress, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have created a Dynamic Menu in ionic project and for each menu item I have to pass the API call to fetch the selected page-data.

1. I have passed the ID of the menu clicked from `app.component.ts` to `remote-service.ts`.
2. I need to fetch the data from the WordPress DB and i have found the API calls method.

**app.html**

```
<button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of menuinformations" (click)="openApage(p.id)">
   {{p.title.rendered}}
</button>
```

Here `menuinformations` contains the JSON array of the pages that are to be displayed in the menu.

[image]

**app.component.ts**

```
openApage(pageinfo) {
 var pagedetails = this.service.getSinglePage(pageinfo).subscribe(
    data => {
        this.pageinformations = data
    });
 console.log(pagedetails);
    this.nav.push(AboutusPage, {
        pageinfodetails: pagedetails
    });
}
```

**remote-service.ts**

```
getSinglePage(pageinfo)
  {
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers })
    let URL ="http://your-domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/"+pageinfo;
    return this.http.get(URL).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

I am successfully getting the page ID to the `remote-service.ts` file. But unable to fetch the data from the api response.

When i paste the **URL** in the browser it fetches the data as JSON Format.

My need is that when I click on the menu an API call needs to be made and the data is to be fetched so what can i do for that.

Comment: are there any errors?

Comment: Object { closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: […], syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, syncErrorThrowable: false, isStopped: false, destination: {…} } app.component.ts:61:4 - This is the error that has been provided.

Comment: which ionic angular version is this? Are you using http from angular/http?

Comment: "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",  "typescript": "~2.6.2", "@angular/http": "5.2.9",

Comment: ok.. and are you importing Http from `@angular/http` or `@angular/common/http` ?

Comment: import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

Comment: I need to fetch the data from WPDB using the `providers` in ionic and display it in the Page as per the menu selected.

Comment: remove `.map(res => res.json())` and try

Comment: Will check and let you know in this @SurajRao

Comment: Now i have tried these two after removing the .map(res=>res.json())

Comment: 1. console.log(URL);     2. console.log(this.http.get(URL));

Comment: For the `log 1` I have got this OP - http://your-domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/99

Comment: For the `log 2` I have obtained this: Object { _isScalar: false, _subscribe: XHRConnection/this.response<() } remote-service.ts:43:3

Comment: But when i paste the URL in the browser obtained from `log 1` the JSON is obtained perfectly. I hope so there is no error in WP API functions.